# PYTHON INTERSECTION WITH 3 LISTS

Tags: python

I have to find an intersection between 3 lists with the same format(?)

I know how to do it btw two lists, like below:

```
    l=list(input("input:"))
    m=list(input("input:"))
    def intersect(l, m):
      return list(set(l) & set(m))
```

But it seems to not work with 3 lists!!!

```
a = list(input("Input:"))
b = list(input("Input:"))
c = list(input("Input:"))
def intersect(a, b, c):
  return list(set(a) & set(b) & set(c))

print intersect(a, b, c)
```

For example, if I input
123
213
312
it should return

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: I cannot understand at all why your input should give `[1, 3]` as output. Please explain in detail the algorithm you would like to use.

Comment: I would like to get inputs with the same values in same places between the lists

Comment: Are you saying that you want to compare adjacent pairs of elements, so `[1 2 3]` and `[2 1 3]` gives `3` as the number in the same place in both lists, then `[2 1 3]` and `[3 1 2]` gives `1`?

Comment: `set()` doesn't care of order - so `set([1, 2, 3])` and `set([2, 1, 3])` are the same set and `set([1, 2, 3]) & set([2, 1, 3])` gives `{1,2,3}`. You would have use `zip(a,b)`  to check elements with the same position on list - `[x for x, y in zip([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3]) if x==y]` gives `[3]`

Comment: ohh thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

`set()` doesn't care of order so `set([1, 2, 3])` and `set([2, 1, 3])` are the same set and `set([1, 2, 3]) & set([2, 1, 3])` gives `{1,2,3}`

You have to use `zip(a,b)` to get pairs and check pairs

```
a = list("123")
b = list("213")
c = list("312")

def intersect(a, b, c):
    p = [x for x, y in zip(a, b) if x==y]    
    q = [x for x, y in zip(b, c) if x==y]    
    r = [x for x, y in zip(c, a) if x==y]    
    return p + q + r

print(intersect(a, b, c))
```

Result:

```
['3', '1']
```

You can eventually sort it to get `['1', '3']`

```
    return sorted(p + q + r)
```